# Phonertc demo only shows blank screen when call is started

Tags: objective-c, phonertc

I am using the phonertc demo project on iOS platform. The setup is done properly and app is deployed on iphone and iPad. But when I am calling a peer it just shows blank screen in the video controller div on the page. I am not sure what is happening, not able to get the code work. Please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the steps in the Wiki for running the an PhoneRTC app on an iOS device:
(https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/wiki/Installation)

> For iOS, follow these steps:
>
> Go platforms/ios and click on [ProjectName].xcodeproj to open it with
>   XCode Go to your project settings In General, change Deployment Target
>   to 7.0 or above Go to Build Settings and change:
>
> a. Valid Architectures => armv7
>
> b. Build Active Architecture Only => No
>
> c. Runpath Search Paths => $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
>
> d. Objective-C Bridging Header =>
>   [ProjectName]/Plugins/com.dooble.phonertc/Bridging-Header.h
>
> e. Embedded content contains Swift Code => yes
>
> Repeat steps 4a. - 4c. for the CordovaLib project
>
> Make sure your build target is an actual iPhone or iPad running on the
>   arm7 architecture. The iPhone and iPad simulators are not emulators,
>   and only run on i386. The compiled RTC libraries for ios have been
>   built for arm7.